# Do flow refinements not propagate "up"?

Tags: flowtype

I was suprised to see that [this example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKGAhhgQLxgDeYsJA5gFxgBGccMeJAdmAL7ooAVx4BjDAEs4fKJIBOAZwzE8OABTKyeFsW0BKGqjBhJUMJtLkAdPQaHaxk2EV4xMgCaqNW8vqcmwMBgGAAWkopgCHDyANaRYXDCDKFMAWBBLm6e3uq0diy+eLYwjAL+JoKCqCLiUjJZ7jxe5D5WOjR0pcwh8sIE-A78QA) doesn't typecheck:

```
/* @flow */

type State = { flag: boolean }

function firstStep(state: State) {
  if (state.flag) { 
    secondStep(state)
    // this works though:
    // secondStep({ flag: state.flag })
  }
}

function secondStep(state: { flag: true }) {}

3: type State = { flag: boolean }
                    ^ boolean. Expected boolean literal `true`
13: function secondStep(state: { flag: true }) {}
                                   ^ boolean literal `true`
```

Flow knows it can refine `state.flag` to `true`, but it doesn't know that `state` can be refined to `{ flag: true }`. Is that expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with many subtype relationships that look fine on the surface, this is ruined by mutability. `secondStep` could retain a reference to `state`, and `firstStep` could later change `state.flag` to `false`.

However, this does work if you use [disjoint unions:](https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/07/03/Disjoint-Unions.html)

```
type State = { flag: true } | { flag: false };
```

([tryflow](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKGAhhgQLxgDeYsJA5gFxgYBOArgQL5gA+NOjEYsoJGAGceAbnRQOAOwDGGAJZwFdVWwkZieHAApdZPC2KmAlDVRgwqqGGOlyAOnoNrtW3bBSlGgAm+kYm5JY+dsDArAAWqhJgCHBsANaJGLFwHAyxTJF+eAEKweRGtB4sYXjuwgxg3BG+YNFgAKJsbClgJIl4AB74KniB+c3VtYxgVGKSeLJ23KhLqPLKahqFxaUGzqYsFXUs7FwNXtxAA))

You may find that disjoint unions suit your use case better anyway, since then you can have different properties in your `State` object depending on the value of the flag.

Note that in this case, Flow does not allow you to set `state.flag` to `false`, so the refinement can hold in `secondStep`.

Comment: It wouldn't be sound to allow passing `state` to `secondStep` because `secondStep` could hold on to a reference to `state`, then `firstStep` could mutate `state.flag` to false. Disjoint unions fix that because `flag` is effectively immutable once you're in one branch of the union or the other.

Comment: Good catch. I'll edit my answer to include this info.

Comment: Ah, really interesting point @RyanCavanaugh. I was wondering if something like that was the issue. Bummer!